# Set minimum date to be current date + a day in android datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

How can I make on the calendar user to be able to choose dates from `current date + 4 days`. For example if user go to calendar to show directly 4 days ahead and unable to chose date before that?
I've using custom date and timepickers from tutorial and I'm not so sure how and what to do. Here is the onCreate for calendar

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reservation);
    custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
            new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                        Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                        String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                        String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                        int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                        String AM_PM) {
                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker)).setText(calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    + "-" + (monthNumber+1) + "-" + year
                                    + " " + hour24 + ":" + min);
                                    //+ " " + AM_PM);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });

    /**
     * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
     * false
     */
    custom.set24HourFormat(false);
    /**
     * Pass Directly current data and time to show when it pop up
     */
    custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());

    findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    custom.showDialog();
                }
});
```

Here is part of `CustomDateTimePicker.java`

```
public class CustomDateTimePicker implements OnClickListener {
private DatePicker datePicker;
private TimePicker timePicker;
private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

private final int SET_DATE = 100, SET_TIME = 101, SET = 102, CANCEL = 103;

private Button btn_setDate, btn_setTime, btn_set, btn_cancel;

private Calendar calendar_date = null;

private Activity activity;

private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

private Dialog dialog;

private boolean is24HourView = true, isAutoDismiss = true;

private int selectedHour, selectedMinute;

public CustomDateTimePicker(Activity a,
    ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) {
activity = a;
iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

dialog = new Dialog(activity);
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        resetData();
    }
});

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
View dialogView = getDateTimePickerLayout();
dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
}

public View getDateTimePickerLayout() {
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_match_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_wrap_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams frame_match_wrap = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

LinearLayout linear_main = new LinearLayout(activity);
linear_main.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
linear_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linear_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

LinearLayout linear_child = new LinearLayout(activity);
linear_child.setLayoutParams(linear_wrap_wrap);
linear_child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout linear_top = new LinearLayout(activity);
linear_top.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

btn_setDate = new Button(activity);
btn_setDate.setLayoutParams(button_params);
btn_setDate.setText("DATE");
btn_setDate.setId(SET_DATE);
btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);

btn_setTime = new Button(activity);
btn_setTime.setLayoutParams(button_params);
btn_setTime.setText("TIME");
btn_setTime.setId(SET_TIME);
btn_setTime.setOnClickListener(this);

linear_top.addView(btn_setDate);
linear_top.addView(btn_setTime);

viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(activity);
viewSwitcher.setLayoutParams(frame_match_wrap);

datePicker = new DatePicker(activity);
timePicker = new TimePicker(activity);
timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        selectedHour = hourOfDay;
        selectedMinute = minute;
    }
});

viewSwitcher.addView(timePicker);
viewSwitcher.addView(datePicker);

LinearLayout linear_bottom = new LinearLayout(activity);
linear_match_wrap.topMargin = 8;
linear_bottom.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

btn_set = new Button(activity);
btn_set.setLayoutParams(button_params);
btn_set.setText("SET");
btn_set.setId(SET);
btn_set.setOnClickListener(this);

btn_cancel = new Button(activity);
btn_cancel.setLayoutParams(button_params);
btn_cancel.setText("CANCEL");
btn_cancel.setId(CANCEL);
btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

linear_bottom.addView(btn_set);
linear_bottom.addView(btn_cancel);

linear_child.addView(linear_top);
linear_child.addView(viewSwitcher);
linear_child.addView(linear_bottom);

linear_main.addView(linear_child);

return linear_main;
}

public void showDialog() {
if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
    if (calendar_date == null)
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

    selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

    datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000);
    /*
    datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

    */

    dialog.show();

    btn_setDate.performClick();
}
}

public void setAutoDismiss(boolean isAutoDismiss) {
    this.isAutoDismiss = isAutoDismiss;
}  

public void dismissDialog() {
    if (!dialog.isShowing())
       dialog.dismiss();
}

public void setDate(Calendar calendar) {
   if (calendar != null)
    calendar_date = calendar;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
   if (date != null) {
    calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_date.setTime(date);
   }
}

public void setDate(int year, int month, int day) {
   if (month < 12 && month >= 0 && day < 32 && day >= 0 && year > 100
        && year < 3000) {
    calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_date.set(year, month, day);

}

}

public void setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format, int minute) {
if (hourIn24Format < 24 && hourIn24Format >= 0 && minute >= 0
        && minute < 60) {
    if (calendar_date == null)
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
            minute);

    is24HourView = true;
}
}

public void setTimeIn12HourFormat(int hourIn12Format, int minute,
    boolean isAM) {
if (hourIn12Format < 13 && hourIn12Format > 0 && minute >= 0
        && minute < 60) {
    if (hourIn12Format == 12)
        hourIn12Format = 0;

    int hourIn24Format = hourIn12Format;

    if (!isAM)
        hourIn24Format += 12;

    if (calendar_date == null)
        calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
            minute);

    is24HourView = false;
}
}

public void set24HourFormat(boolean is24HourFormat) {
   is24HourView = is24HourFormat;
}

public interface ICustomDateTimeListener {
  public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
        Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
        String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
        String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName, int hour24,
        int hour12, int min, int sec, String AM_PM);

public void onCancel();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case SET_DATE:
    btn_setTime.setEnabled(true);
    btn_setDate.setEnabled(false);
    viewSwitcher.showNext();
    break;

case SET_TIME:
    btn_setTime.setEnabled(false);
    btn_setDate.setEnabled(true);
    viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
    break;

case SET:
    if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null) {
        int month = datePicker.getMonth();
        int year = datePicker.getYear();
        int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();


        calendar_date.set(year, month, day, selectedHour,
                selectedMinute);

        iCustomDateTimeListener.onSet(dialog, calendar_date,
                calendar_date.getTime(), calendar_date
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR),
                getMonthFullName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                getMonthShortName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date
                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                getWeekDayFullName(calendar_date
                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                getWeekDayShortName(calendar_date
                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), calendar_date
                        .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                getHourIn12Format(calendar_date
                        .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)), calendar_date
                        .get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar_date
                        .get(Calendar.SECOND), getAMPM(calendar_date));
    }
    if (dialog.isShowing() && isAutoDismiss)
        dialog.dismiss();
    break;

case CANCEL:
    if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null)
        iCustomDateTimeListener.onCancel();
    if (dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.dismiss();
    break;
}
}

public static String convertDate(String date, String fromFormat,
    String toFormat) {
try {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
    Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(d);

    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
    simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
    date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return date;
}

private String getMonthFullName(int monthNumber) {
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
   simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
   String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

   return monthName;
}

private String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

return monthName;
}

private String getWeekDayFullName(int weekDayNumber) {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

return weekName;
}

private String getWeekDayShortName(int weekDayNumber) {
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

return weekName;
}

private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) {
int hourIn12Format = 0;

if (hour24 == 0)
    hourIn12Format = 12;
else if (hour24 <= 12)
    hourIn12Format = hour24;
else
    hourIn12Format = hour24 - 12;

return hourIn12Format;
}

private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) {
String ampm = (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == (Calendar.AM)) ? "AM"
        : "PM";
return ampm;
}

private void resetData() {
  calendar_date = null;
is24HourView = true;
}

public static String pad(int integerToPad) {
if (integerToPad >= 10 || integerToPad < 0)
    return String.valueOf(integerToPad);
else
    return "0" + String.valueOf(integerToPad);
}

}
```

UPDATE: I got error on this

```
public void setDate(Calendar calendar) {
if (calendar != null)
    calendar_date = calendar;
}
```

And the error say

**The method setDate(Calendar) in the type CustomDateTimePicker is not applicable for the arguments (long)**

LogCat error

```
11-24 05:18:12.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1338): Process: com.reserveme, PID: 1338
11-24 05:18:12.196: E/AndroidRuntime(1338): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromDate: Mon Nov 24 05:18:11 EST 2014 does not precede toDate: Mon Nov 24 05:18:08 EST 2014
```

Comment: DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddUpdateActivity.this, datePicker, year, month, day);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000); for setting minimum date as current day

Comment: Where should I put this .. in `onCreate`? or `onSet`

Comment: put datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000); before dialog.show();

Comment: I have `dialog.show()` in `CustomDateTimePicker.java` and `custom.showDialog();` in `mainActivity.java`. And on both places I get error. If I put it in `MainActivity` I get `The method getDatePicker() is undefined for the type EditText` in `CustomDatePicker.java` is `The method getDatePicker() is undefined for the type DatePicker`

Comment: try removing  getDatePicker(). ot use this. as you have created a custom datePicker

Comment: I've updated my question with the error on `setDate`

Comment: After I put this `custom.setDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);` since I use `custom` I changed `datePicker` to `custom`

Comment: No you have to add this line in custom class before dialog.show()

Comment: Now I got app crashed with this error in Logcat. Updated in question

Comment: please replace - 1000 with - 10000

Comment: Ok, now it's open the calendar but I'm still able to choose past days. My goal is to set minimum date to choose current date + 3 days so total 4 days ahead

Comment: Sorry, on `first` open of calendar I'm able to choose past dates. On `second` open of calendar I'm not able. Why is that?

Comment: will you comment these lines and check ?? datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

Comment: I've commented them. It is really strange behavior of the calendar. I still see past dates and can select. But when I choose for example yesterday (23.11.2014) I got `23.11.2100`. I mean the current Yeas is not 2014 but is 2100

Comment: can you mail me your code?

Comment: I've put in the question full `CustomDateTimePicker.java` I can also paste in `pastebin` bot MainActivity and CustomDateTimePicker.java if you want

Comment: Ok and your Layout too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65508/discussion-between-jason-paddle-and-shrinivas).